# Android: integrate app into text edit menus (copy/paste/etc)

Tags: android

I want ask if is possible integrate my app with any text edit in android.

If I press and hold finger on any text edit in android, it shows me pop up menu with options (Copy, Paste...). My application is for text optimization, so I want add an item into this pop up menu for my application, so you can choose to optimize that text. Its possible?

(sorry for my English)

Comment: It is not possible to do that.

similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678264/add-method-into-android-copy-paste-global-contextual-menu

Comment: This feature now seems to be available in Lolipop/Marshmallow... Seeing additional entry in the context menu for the app 'WorbWeb'. How is this done?

Comment: Found it... http://stackoverflow.com/a/38539059/1458751