# Add Method Into Android Copy/Paste Global Contextual Menu?

Tags: java, android

On textboxes in Android, onLongClick reveals a contextual menu that has the copy/paste methods. Is there any way to add another option (say, "copy to [insert application here]")?

It's trivial to do it within my application's contextual menu because I can just override onLongClick. My "copy to [insert application here]" method, however, would only work in my app's contextual menu; not in the default messaging's text selection contextual menu, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: what a pitty, did you find any other solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add to other applications' context menus.

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be done. See the article on [copy and paste](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible nowadays. You need to register that your activity can process text with `android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT` intent filter.