# How to add custom item on Global long press Contextmenu like Translate and Wikipedia

Tags: android, contextmenu

[image]

I want to know how google translate and wikipedia app did to add their item on the webview long press context menu.
P.S. This screenshot is from Nexus 5 6.0.1 version.

Answer (score 6):

They added an activity that supports `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` via an `<intent-filter>`:

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

On the `Intent` delivered to the activity (obtained via `getIntent()`), `EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT` will hold some text, or `EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY` will hold it if the text is read-only. The text will be what was highlighted when the user chose the menu option that started this activity.

The activity will be invoked via `startActivityForResult()`. The result `Intent` can have its own `EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT` value, which will be the replacement text.

Comment: @penghaitao I can't seem to get it to work. Can you please share a working snippet?

Comment: @penghaitao Yes I am running from an Android 6.0 emulator.

Comment: @Strategist I only add this intent filter and it works. Did you add this to the right position?

Answer (score 2):

A complete example:

**AndroidManifest.xml** - code specific to activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In **Activity.java** - code specific to onResume():

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    // Get Intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Clear the intent to prevent again receiving on resuming Main
    setIntent(new Intent());

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
            intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT) &&
            intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT)) {
        // Text received for processing in readonly - i.e. from non-editable EditText
        boolean textToProcessIsReadonly = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, false);
        // Text received for processing
        CharSequence textToProcess = intent.getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);
    }
}
```

In **Activity.java** - code to send back the processed text:

```
private void sendProcessedText() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, textProcessed);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.finish();
}
```